# Как удалить историю чата

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Как можно очистить историю чата и выйти в исходное состояние с кнопкой старт (возможно с подтверждением). Есть метод messages.deleteHistory, но как его применить не понятно

Comment: А что мешает попробовать, что делает этот метод?

Comment: это API самого телегрма, а не API бота

Comment: @РашенБеар, я же написал, что  не знаю как применить этот метод, поэтому тут, поэтому задаю вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Можно только удалить сообщения. Еще можно кикнуть всех из чата, тогда им придутся заново заходить, и наверняка они увидят кнопку.

Comment: Тогда что делает messages.deleteHistory